# SSIS Flat File Connection Manager Editor Column

Tags: ssis

I have a text file where it contains the data as (exactly as) below:

```
"AH7" "Gary McPherson" "dabjlaidiPidhhbK" "21/12/2012" "gbxq5w" "21/12/2012" "01" "811" "" "0" "" "" no no "GMP" "" "" "AH7" no yes "" ""
```

When I provide Column delimiter with two double quotes with space in between (" ") manually, I am getting Column 0 beginning with "AH7 but I want to start with only AH7. Can anyone help me how to get column 0 with out beginning with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing text qualifiers with column delimiters.

In your case the double quotes are your text qualifier and the blank is your column delimiter.

Comment: I have the similar data as shown below.
"id" "amount" "category" "widget" "" ""
"2" "2145" "e" "1dec" "hello world"
"3" "24.5" "r" "21dec" "hi"

What to be set in "General (Text qualifier & Header row delimiter) & Columns (Row delimiter & column delimiter)"

Comment: There's no way to tell because your example is not recognizable in this comment. Edit your question and the properly formatted example.